# AWS Lambda .NET Core task Fail to upload to S3

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, azure-devops

I'm using the task LambdaNETCoreDeploy for dotnet in my Azure DevOps pipeline

The task was working fine until up to last week.

I tried to run my pipeline and the task failed to upload the package to S3.

I have verified the credentials used for the task are live and have access to the S3 buket.
Any help is appreciated.

### Below are the logs from the pipeline

Lambda project successfully packaged:

##C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\busTokensLambdaFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-638339604130850185.zip Uploading to S3. (Bucket: riyo-serverless-code/busTokens Key: riyo-functions-busTokensLambdaFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-638339604130850185.zip)

**Error uploading to riyo-functions-busTokensLambdaFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-638339604130850185.zip in bucket riyo-serverless-code/busTokens: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

```
##[debug]Exit code 4294967295 received from tool 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe' ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe' ##[debug]task result: Failed ##[error]Error:
The process 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe' failed with exit code 4294967295 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: The process 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe' failed with exit code
4294967295 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: The process 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-lambda.exe' failed with exit code 4294967295
```

Comment: Did you try updating or creating a new of the related AWS service connection?

Comment: 'I have verified the credentials used for the task are live and have access to the S3 bucket.' - how? did you run CLI commands in the pipeline using the same credentials? what is your pipeline definition? there's key information missing from your question.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I ran the cli on my local dev machine using the same creds that I configured in the pipeline. Looking at the history of the pipeline, last time when it worked it was using Amazon.lamda.tools 5.8.0 but now LambdaNETCoreDeploy task is auto upgrading it to 5.8.1. I'm thinking may be this new version is causing the problem.

I stalled the 5.8.0 in the pipeline using the dotnet install task, but LambdaNETCoreDeploy cannot find it and it auto upgrades it to 5.8.1. I wish there was a way to tell LambdaNETCoreDeploy  to use a particular verison of the Amazon.lamda.tools.

Comment: The S3 bucket in the task was configured as riyo-serverless-code/busTokens This worked fine with Amazonlamda.tools version 5.8.0 but however 5.8.1 throws the error.

I set the bucket as riyo-serverless-code and then prefix to /busTokens to make it work.